# i lost my password and 12 word can i recover my password?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I am new user  i crate my bitcoin wallet on zebpay   then my friend tell me  to creat bitcoin wallet on blockchain.info   as he suggest me i creat new bitcoine wallet  and send  40000 INR in new wallet after a week i try to open my wallet but  i forgot my password  when i try to recover it  system says to 12 word  but i have no knowledge about 12 word   now how i recover my money  please anybody help me

Comment: Please get in touch with the customer support.

Answer (score 2):

The only option left is to contact the support: https://blockchain.zendesk.com/

Comment: @PieterWuille: Actually, it seems to be implied in the second sentence that it was.

Comment: @PieterWuille it is explicitly stated in the first line.